# Customizar mensagens de erro do CSRF protection no CodeIgniter

Tags: html, codeigniter, csrf, redirect

No `CodeIgniter`, caso eu der um *reload* <kbd>F5</kbd> na página de um formulário, é retornado o erro `The action you have requested is not allowed`. Uma proteção contra `CSRF`.

Como eu faço para personalizar o `HTML` dessa mensagem de erro?

Ao invés de exibir uma mensagem `HTML` de erro, como fazer para que eu use a função `redirect()` e leve o usuário para a página inicial?

Comment: Eu personalizado desta forma: $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Você não tem permissão para visualizar fechamentos.');

Comment: E embaixo você pode colocar um redirect... mas depende da condição e do controller/model que está elaborando... Se puder postar eles, acho que fica melhor para compreender o que exatamente você precisa.

Answer (score 1):

A proteção de CSRF está na classe `CI_Security`, que é instanciada antes dos helpers e libs.

Você pode tentar extender o funcionamento da classe.

Talvez isso te ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406922/prevent-from-displaying-the-default-csrf-error-page-in-codeigniter